# Any mistake of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY statement

Tags: mysql

I would like to know what is the problem with the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY statement below. It keep complain ***Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A.NoTrans' in 'field list'***

```
INSERT INTO tableA (id, totalTrans)
SELECT A.id, A.NoTrans
FROM (
    SELECT id, NoTrans, LastUpdatedOn 
    FROM tableB
    UNION
    SELECT id, TotalTrans, LastUpdatedOn 
    FROM tableC 
) A
WHERE A.LastUpdatedOn >= '2015-06-26' AND A.LastUpdatedOn <=  '2015-06-27' 
GROUP BY A.id, A.NoTrans
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE totalTrans = A.NoTrans
```

That is no issue if the statement is without ***ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE totalTrans = A.NoTrans***

```
INSERT INTO tableA (id, totalTrans)
SELECT A.id, A.NoTrans
FROM (
    SELECT id, NoTrans, LastUpdatedOn 
    FROM tableB
    UNION
    SELECT id, TotalTrans, LastUpdatedOn 
    FROM tableC 
) A
WHERE A.LastUpdatedOn >= '2015-06-26' AND A.LastUpdatedOn <=  '2015-06-27' 
GROUP BY A.id, A.NoTrans
```

I tried to put the alias for UNION column, but the issue still happen, such as

```
SELECT A.id, A.NoTrans AS 'NoOfTrans'
......
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE totalTrans = NoOfTrans
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table alias `A` is not recognized in the `on duplicate key update`.  It is part of the `select` statement, but not the `insert` statement.  Instead, use the `VALUES()` function:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (id, totalTrans)
SELECT A.id, A.NoTrans
FROM (
    SELECT id, NoTrans, LastUpdatedOn 
    FROM tableB
    UNION
    SELECT id, TotalTrans, LastUpdatedOn 
    FROM tableC 
) A
WHERE A.LastUpdatedOn >= '2015-06-26' AND A.LastUpdatedOn <=  '2015-06-27' 
GROUP BY A.id, A.NoTrans
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE totalTrans = values(totalTrans);
```